# Meaning of word "clutch" in this text

Tags: meaning, context

> Martin Rees recalls his mentor Dennis Sciama's dogged commitment to
>   the Steady State Model: "For him, as for its inventors, it had a deep
>   philosophical appeal--the universe existed, from everlasting to
>   everlasting, in a uniquely self-consistent state. When conflicting
>   evidence emerged, Sciama therefore sought a loophole (even an unlikely
>   seeming one) rather as a **defense lawyer clutches** at any argument to
>   rebut the prosecution case" (Martin Rees, Before the Beginning, with a
>   Foreword by Stephen Hawking [Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1997], p.
>   41).

The word "clutch" has a lot of different meanings, according to this dictionary, for example: [link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clutch). I'm not a native english speaker, so I have difficulty to identify which one fits better at that context. Could you help me?

Comment: In the above sense it means "grab" or "take hold of".

Comment: I was understanding "clutch" as a plural noun. So it is a verb, in the sentence? Now it makes sense.

Comment: Yep, as used above it's a verb.

Comment: @HotLicks - in ME, "muckle onto"

Comment: @Rob_Ster  - in Dothraki, {swordstab take}

Comment: And, of course, it's also a verb (as well as a noun) when operating a standard transmission vehicle.

Comment: This is basic English. @David - do you not know *how* to use a dictionary? I would probably closevote this even on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To seize, grip or hold tightly.

The [link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clutch) you cite provides an easy way for determining the meaning.

The presence of "at" following clutches, indicates that this is the verb form not the noun form (since you can't "noun at" something).

Yes, there are several verb meanings listed, however; there are only 3 meanings that can be used with an object, and one of those specifically references "directed at a person".

The 2 valid definitions show that "clutches" has to mean holding or grabbing with intensity.

Comment: I didn't realized that there is a "a" before "defense lawyers". So I've thought "clutches" was a plural noun related to the lawyers. But since there is that "a", "clutches" cannot be plural, and so has to be a verb. I'm ashamed of myself now because I see my mistake.

Comment: No worries! Hopefully this exercise helps give you a few tools to use next time you run into one of our "weird English verbs". :-)

Answer (score 1):

It means to grab and hold on to something desperately.

Comment: I didn't realized that "clutches" was a 3rd person verb and not a plural noun. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You said, "I didn't realize that there is an 'a' before 'defense lawyers'."

There isn't. The sentence says "as a defense lawyer clutches...."

The sentence is using a singular subject to refer to defense lawyers as a general group. For example, "Doctors say that a baby can recognize its mother's voice, even in the womb." (I just made that up.) The sentence isn't talking about one baby, but about every baby.

Every defense lawyer will grab hold of *any* argument in an attempt to rebut the prosecution.